# C++ WinSock sending files

Tags: c++, winsock, ifstream

Recently, i've been assigned a client/server project, which is basically a chat room, where files can be sent and recieved, and we can use webcams.
I'm currently working on the file transfer part, and after looking at some online tutorials, i've noticed most of them use offsets to write into their buffers, then they write the whole buffer into their new file.

To replicate that kind of code, i've set up 2 buffers, one on the client side, the other on the server side. On the server side, i read 8192 bytes from my file, into the buffer, then i send it into the client side, which recieves it, and adds it to my buffer. Problem is, after the second file transfer, every single transfer it does, it's a SOCKET_ERROR, which probably means something's not quite right.

server:

```
std::ifstream readFile;
        readFile.open(FileName, std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
        if (!readFile)
        {
            std::cout << "unable to open file" << std::endl;
        }
        int FileSize = readFile.tellg();
        readFile.seekg(0);
        int remainingBytes = 0;
        uint32_t FileSize32t = (uint32_t)FileSize;

        FileSize32t = htonl(FileSize32t);
        send(connections[ID], (char*)&FileSize32t, sizeof(uint32_t), 0);
        int sent_bytes = 0;
        int offset = 0;
        char data[8192];
        remainingBytes = FileSize;
        int i = 0;
        while (i<6)
        {
            readFile.read(data, 8192);
            if (remainingBytes < 8192)
            {
                sent_bytes = send(connections[ID], data+offset, remainingBytes, 0);
                remainingBytes -= sent_bytes;
                offset += sent_bytes;
            }
            else
            {                   
                sent_bytes = send(connections[ID], data+offset, 8192, 0);
                if (sent_bytes == SOCKET_ERROR)
                {
                    std::cout << "erro" << std::endl;
                }
                remainingBytes -= sent_bytes;
                offset += sent_bytes;
                std::cout <<"offset: "<< offset << std::endl;
                std::cout << "Sent bytes: " << sent_bytes << std::endl;
                std::cout << "remaining bytes: " << remainingBytes << std::endl;
            }       
            i++;
        }
```

Client:

```
char data[8192];
        std::ofstream writeFile;
        writeFile.open("Putin.jpg", std::ios::binary);
        int bytesReceieved = 0;
        int totalBytesReceieved = 0;
        int i = 0;
        while (i<6)
        {

            if (recvFileSize - totalBytesReceieved < 8192)
            {
                bytesReceieved = recv(connection, data+totalBytesReceieved, recvFileSize - totalBytesReceieved, 0);
                totalBytesReceieved += bytesReceieved;
            }
            else
            {
                bytesReceieved = recv(connection, data + totalBytesReceieved, 8192, 0);
                totalBytesReceieved += bytesReceieved;
                std::cout << totalBytesReceieved << std::endl;
            }   
            i++;
        }
        writeFile.write(data, totalBytesReceieved);
        std::cout << "transferência terminada, bytes recebidos: " << totalBytesReceieved << std::endl;

        writeFile.close();
```

Do note that this is just a test program, and it's preety much one of my first interactions with C++. I've been told this probably isn't the best way to start off with C++, but i need this assignment done until the 15th of september, so i need to finish it regardless. If you find any errors or problems besides my original issue do feel free to point them out and if you can, explain me why it's wrong.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I can send ints and strings already! Files are the only thing giving me problems atm :(. It returned -1, which is SOCKET_ERROR, but there's not much to take from that.

Comment: `SOCKET_ERROR` means you need to take a look at `errno` (POSIX) or `WSAGetLastError()` (Windows) to get a more descriptive error code.

Comment: Bad address.
The system detected an invalid pointer address in attempting to use a pointer argument of a call. This error occurs if an application passes an invalid pointer value, or if the length of the buffer is too small. For instance, if the length of an argument, which is a [sockaddr](sockaddr-2.md) structure, is smaller than the sizeof(sockaddr).



This is the Error apparently. Can't say i'd know how to fix it though. 
When i saw the tutorials, my logic was that data+offset would increase the size of the buffer by offset, and write starting at that memory address.

Comment: One possibility: If `recvFileSize - totalBytesReceieved` winds up negative, the `len` parameter probably becomes insanely large (it's unsigned).

Comment: Huh. How would i go about fixing that?

Comment: I mean i could try to make sure it doesn't go negative, but that would just loop over and over probably, and the file would probably be corrupted.

Comment: Me, I'd have a loop that looked something like `while (recvFileSize) { bytesReceieved = recv(connection, data, std::min(sizeof(data), recvFileSize, 0); if (bytesReceieved >0) { writeFile.write(data, bytesReceieved); recvFileSize -= bytesReceieved;} else { abort the transfer } }`. This allows file sizes greater than 8k. Right now you're probably stomping the stack which is possibly causing the problem you're seeing.

Comment: I've figured it out finally! I was writing totalBytesRecieved when what i wanted to write was bytes recieved, and i had to write every time i recieved stuff from the server. Totally dumb of me.